# How to hide SQL errors from user in Vbulletin Forum 4.2.2?

Tags: php, forum, vbulletin

When case sql error on my forums on 4.2.2 version, users can view raw sql query, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors>
<error><![CDATA[<p>Database Error</p>]]></error>
<error_html><![CDATA[<p>Ошибка базы данных в vBulletin 4.2.2</p>
<p>Invalid SQL:

SELECT MAX(dateline) AS lastpost, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM vb_usernote AS usernote
WHERE userid =;<p>
<p>
<strong>Ошибка MySQL</strong> : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3<br />
<strong>Номер ошибки</strong> : 1064<br />
<strong>Дата запроса</strong> : Wednesday, April 15th 2020 @ 12:02:14 PM<br />
<strong>Дата ошибки</strong> : Wednesday, April 15th 2020 @ 12:02:14 PM<br />
<strong>Скрипт</strong> : http://parapa.mail.ru/forums/activity.php<br />
<strong>Реферер</strong> : <br />
<strong>Имя класса</strong> : vB_Database_Slave_MySQLi<br />
<strong>Версия MySQL</strong> : <br />
</p>]]></error_html>
</errors>
```

How can I hide these details?

Comment: // Turn off error reporting
error_reporting(0);
source: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_error_reporting.asp

Comment: Maybe fix the query instead of ignoring it ? 
Aperently the " WHERE userid=" the userid is missing !

Comment: @TimeParadox but it not php error, it print Vbulletin only sql error

Comment: @Iason Yes, it right, but I also want to hide any error from users

Comment: Cross-posted from https://forum.vbulletin.com/forum/vbulletin-4/vbulletin-4-questions-problems-and-troubleshooting/4438494-how-to-hide-sql-error-from-user

Comment: @TimeParadox Do not switch PHP error reporting. If anything you should switch display  off. I don't think it would help in this case, because this looks like a custom error thrown by vBulletin.